# Understanding the layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-frontend

I'm creating a layout to test my skills. I have faced a problem about the layout:

I created a bar (see the image) but this one is overlapped by the **card** divs (the 400x200 images). The few elements in the form (inside the **bar** div) are placed at the bottom of the page where they should have been but the colored bar is placed in a wrong way. 
You can see with your eyes the result and the code. 
I attached a photo of the result I would like to reach to.

[image]

Unwanted result:
[image]

```js
$(function(){

    var $buttonNav = $('.header__icon-bar');
     var degree = 45;
  $buttonNav.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.header__nav').toggleClass('is-open');
    $buttonNav.toggleClass('animate');


  if( $('.header__nav').hasClass('is-open')){
   $('.header__icon-bar').css('transform','rotate(90deg)')
  }else{
   $('.header__icon-bar').css('transform','rotate(0deg)')
  }


});//end of click event

});//end of $(document).ready()
```

```css
/*----------
GENERAL
-----------*/
html,body{ width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body{  background: #eee; }
.animate{
  -webkit-trasform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-trasform: rotate(90deg);
  trasform: rotate(90deg);
}


/*----------
HEADER
-----------*/
.header__nav{  display: block; float: right; margin: 0; padding: 20px; background: #333; margin-top: 50px; position: relative; z-index: 100;}
.header__nav__item{ display: inline-block; margin: 0; }
.header__nav__item a {padding: 30px; padding: 20px; margin: 0; color: white; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; }
.header__nav__item a:hover { background: #ff3333; }

/*----------
cover
-----------*/
.cover{ background-color: #333; height: 80% ; width: 100%;position: relative; margin-top: 90px; padding: 30px;}
.cover__text { color: white; width: 95%; position: relative; left: 40px; }
.cover__text p{ color: #999999; font-size: 20px; }
.line-through{padding: 1px; width: 750px; height: 1px;  background-color:  #e6ccb3; display: table; margin: 0 auto; z-index: 30px;}
.cover__image{ margin:  0; padding:  0; float: left; z-index: 3; width: 600px; height: 400px;  z-index: 20; background-image: url(http://www.dejana.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/550x370.png);
  background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-position: center; }
.cover__button { margin: 0 auto; display: table; padding: 20px}
.cover__button a{ padding: 20px; background-color: #ff3333;border-radius: 5px; text-decoration: none; color: black; font-weight: bold;}
.cover__button a:hover{ background: #eee; color: #ff3333; }


/* HIDING OVERFLOW ELEMENTS
html,body{overflow-x: hidden;}
*/

/*---------
CARD
----------*/
.card{ position: relative; margin-top: 30px;  max-width: 1440px;}
.card__img {float: right; margin: 20px 10px; width: 400px; height: 200px}
.card__img:hover{opacity: 0.5}




/*----------
ICON-BAR
-----------*/
.header__icon-bar{ margin: 0; padding: 10px; background-color: #333; float: left; display: none;}
.header__icon-bar span { padding: 3px 1px; margin: 3px ; background-color: white;}
.header__background{display: none; height: 0px; background-color: #333; margin: 0;}

/*----------
ICON-BAR
-----------*/
.bar{ background-color: #333; height: 50px; border: 1px red solid; margin:0; padding: 0}


/*----------
SMARTPHONE
-----------*/
@media(max-width: 960px) {
  /*header-Menu*/
.header{ width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
.header__nav{ width: 100%; overflow: hidden; height: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.header__nav__item { display: block; padding: 20px; margin: 0; position: relative;}
.header__nav__item a{ width: 100%;padding-right: 100%;}

.is-open{ display: block; height: 255px; background: #333; display: block; margin: 0;}

/*button of spaun menu(nav)*/
.header__icon-bar{ display: block;margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px; float: left; position: absolute;}
.header__background{display: block; background-color:#333; height: 60px; width: 100%}

/*cover*/
.cover{ height: auto; padding: 10px; margin-top: 30px; width: 100%}
.cover__image{  padding:  0; margin: 0; width: 97%; height: 400px; display: block; }
.cover__text{ margin: 0; left: 0; top: 20px; padding: 10px; width: 100%; display: block; overflow-y: scroll;}
.cover__text p {font-size: 16px}
.line-through{ width: 90%}
.cover__button { margin-top: 15px; position: relative; margin-bottom: 10px;}
.cover__button a{ padding: 10px; font-size: 15px;}


/*cards*/
.card{ margin-top: 50px }
.card__img{ margin: 0 ;  padding: 10px 20px; }



}/*END OF @font-face */





















*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}





/*----------
CLEARFIX
-----------*/
.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <header class="header clearfix">
   <div class="header__background">

   <a class="header__icon-bar animate" href="">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
  </a>
</div>


    <ul class="header__nav">
      <li class="header__nav__item">  <a href="#"> Home    </a> </li>
      <li class="header__nav__item">  <a href="#"> Contact </a>    </li>
      <li class="header__nav__item">  <a href="#"> Apply   </a>    </li>
      <li class="header__nav__item">  <a href="#"> About   </a>    </li>
    </ul>


 </header>


<div class="cover">

    <div class="cover__image"></div>


  <div class="cover__text">
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<span class="line-through"></span>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</div>

<div class="cover__button"><a href=""> Buy a New Course</a></div>
</div>


<section class="card">
  <img  class="card__img" src="http://tempuss.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/x400X200.gif.pagespeed.ic.ImNMmRjNoW.png"  />
  <img  class="card__img" src="http://tempuss.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/x400X200.gif.pagespeed.ic.ImNMmRjNoW.png"  />
  <img  class="card__img" src="http://tempuss.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/x400X200.gif.pagespeed.ic.ImNMmRjNoW.png"  />

</section>


<section class="card">
  <img  class="card__img" src="http://tempuss.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/x400X200.gif.pagespeed.ic.ImNMmRjNoW.png"  />
  <img  class="card__img" src="http://tempuss.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/x400X200.gif.pagespeed.ic.ImNMmRjNoW.png"  />
  <img  class="card__img" src="http://tempuss.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/x400X200.gif.pagespeed.ic.ImNMmRjNoW.png"  />

</section>


<div class="bar ">
  <form action="" method="get">

<label for="email">Email</label><input type="email" name="email" value="email@exemple.com">
<input type="submit" value="Iscriviti"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to clear the floats. Try to apply overflow: hidden to the .card class.